# Task status when task has a timer elapsed event

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library

I am using TPL for create parallel tasks. each task has timer elapsed event so every 2 sec it calls another method. This will go on for a long time. However when the status while the timer event is being called the task status is "RanToCompletion". How can the task be this status when the task is calling event timer every few seconds? sample code is below.

```
Task<int>[] tasks = new Task<int>[n];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    tasks[i] = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        Work work = new Work();
        work.doWork();
        return 1;
    }
    );
}

public void doWork()
{
        System.Timers.Timer aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
        aTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(OnTimedEvent);
        aTimer.Start()
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Task body just creates a timer, so the Task is completed when you hit the return. The timer isn't going to block the task.

Is there a problem with the task being completed?  If so, can you give more detail as to why?

FWIW, Task is generally a good fit for a single future value. If you want something to happen every X seconds, either just create/use the timers directly (no need for the Tasks) or consider using something like Observable.Interval to get an ongoing stream of values every X seconds.

Comment: thanks for explanation. But i have a doubt. in this particular case the task will create a thread and the thread will create a timer. So after since the task is complete does the thread terminate?

Comment: When the timer is created does it spawn a independent thread that will keep calling the event?